# Why does bulk load causes indexing on Couchbase Server?

Tags: java, couchbase

I am reading bulk data from a Couchbase bucket and inserting this bulk data to another bucket. I am using couchbase java sdk 1.4.4 version.Using views for reading the whole data.

I am using the set api to insert the data. After inserting the whole data into Couchbase, I am closing the Couchbase client.

Data gets inserted into Couchbase but as soon as it gets inserted, it starts indexing the data which I can see from couch base web console. As per couch base documentation, it should start indexing when we are reading the data , based on STALE parameter.

The other issue which I am facing is, at my java application console, it shows lots of warnings until indexing is not done.

```
jvm 1    | WARN  [OperationFuture] Exception thrown wile executing com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient$15.operationComplete()
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutting down
jvm 1    |      at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.broadcastOp(MemcachedClient.java:298) ~[spymemcached-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
jvm 1    |      at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.broadcastOp(MemcachedClient.java:292) ~[spymemcached-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
jvm 1    |      at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.observe(CouchbaseClient.java:1670) ~[couchbase-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
jvm 1    |      at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.observePoll(CouchbaseClient.java:1803) ~[couchbase-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
jvm 1    |      at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient$15.onComplete(CouchbaseClient.java:1443) ~[couchbase-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
jvm 1    |      at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient$15.onComplete(CouchbaseClient.java:1412) ~[couchbase-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
jvm 1    |      at net.spy.memcached.internal.AbstractListenableFuture$1.run(AbstractListenableFuture.java:117) ~[spymemcached-2.11.4.
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
```

Questions:
Why is index creation starting before reading the views?
Why are there warning messages coming on console?.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using for shutting down the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the Couchbase server manual index are run automatically. Here are the default parameters for the automated index updates.

```
{
     "updateInterval":5000,
     "updateMinChanges":5000,
     "replicaUpdateMinChanges":5000 
}
```

With these setting the system will check every 5 seconds to see if there has been 5000 mutations made to the bucket. If that is true it will start indexing. Once the bulk load code does 5000 **sets** the indexing will began.

You can read more about automated index updates in the [manual](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#).

Comment: Thanks Pappy . You are correct. 
Should we set large  number to start indexing just like we disable indexing in relational dbs to insert bulk load in couchbase?

For shutting down the client , I am using couchbaseClient.shutdown().

Comment: Warning messages were coming because I was shutting down my client before ensuring that all my data is inserted. I have used the countdownlatches and now everything works fine.